# class->methode1()->methode2() what does it mean?

Tags: c++, qt, class, call

Im introducing myself to QT right now and often comming across calls like `class->methode1()->methode2()`. What does this mean? `methode1()` would be a methode of `class`, but what about `methode2()` and how does this notation work out?

Can i split this call to
`class->methode1()`
and
`class->methode2()` and get the same result?

Is this C++ or QT specific?

Comment: This has nothing (specifically) to do with QT. You really need to sit down with an intro C++ book, this is *really* basic stuff.

Comment: You really need to be more specific. There's absolutely no way for us to know if splitting up the call like that would work. Have you tried it and compiled it? That's the easiest way to know if something will work.

Comment: the classes for each method could and probably are different so the splitting would break it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class->methode1()` returns a pointet to an object that provides a method `methode2` you can call immediately. By doing this you create anonymous objects (rvalues if I am not wrong) and you call methods on those objects. You cannl actually say

`class2 = class1->methode();` and then call `class2->methode2();` to achieve the same. (pseudo-code)

Comment: `s/an object/a pointer to an object/` to be precise.

Comment: Yes, very true! Thank you for this small but significant hint.

Comment: Thanks you very much, this answers my question.

Comment: @Rumbleball You are welcome, please check as answer then.

Comment: `class->methode1()` could also return an object of a custom type with an overloaded `operator->`.